# Looking for references: Differencial geometry a unified treatment of smooth and discrete cases

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, discrete-geometry

Hope my question is not too vague.

I've studied John M. Lee "Introduction to smooth manifolds" and now want to move to study differential geometry on simplicial complexes, the goal eventually is to study Laplace-Beltrami operators on graphs. But I want to go slowly and understand first the relationship between differential geometry on simplicial complexes and the smooth one, and then finally relate differential geometry on simplicial complexes to that on graphs.

I found a lot of material on differential geometry focusing on discrete domain separately ([here](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1975-214-00/S0002-9947-1975-0391146-5/S0002-9947-1975-0391146-5.pdf), or [here](http://library.msri.org/books/Book38/files/forman.pdf)). With definition where the discrete case is given as **analogy** of a smooth case, but not as **extension** of one from the another.

I was wondering if there is a unified theory that combines smooth and non-smooth manifolds, such that it includes also discrete manifolds like graphs as a special case?

I could imagine a treatment where one obtains differential geometry on simplexes as a "limit" of the smooth theory where the functions are averaged over simplices (integrated out in some sense) and various differential operators are defined to include not just smooth domains but domains with corners.

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: I think a study of discrete differential geometry should start with discrete calculus.

Comment: @PeterSaveliev thanks for your comment, do you mean that discrete differential geometry arises from the discrete approximation of the relevant operators?  i.e. instead of taking derivative, we do f(n+1) -f(n) on the grid. Do you know any references that follow this approach?

Comment: I believe that, at least to some extent, it is possible to have the discrete analogs of the operators, and of the whole calculus and differential geometry. References are scattered in papers. I am trying to do something in one place, on the most elementary level so far: http://inperc.com/wiki/index.php?title=Calculus_Illustrated.